# Facing issues in Alertbox selenium 3.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

After clicking save button a pop will open and i write a code below to do accept but its not working.

```
   `driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
    Alert succ=driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(succ.getText());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    succ.accept();`
```

[image]

Need Help please.

Comment: Are you getting the text of alert . can u add the snap of that popup

Comment: add some wait after click the save button then do switch on alert. this  may do trick

Comment: added `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of selenium varies according to browser, In some case the actions done in Firefox browser like form filling actions or clicking the button is faster then Chrome browser so your script well executed in chrome but throw error in Firefox so you need to add some pause to make them perform well.

So in your case after clicking the save button selenium executing the command too fast so skip to switch on alert and accept so add some wait using `Thread.sleep();` to make pause

```
driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Alert succ=driver.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println(succ.getText());
Thread.sleep(2000);
succ.accept();
```

Note : It is not recommended to use `Thread.sleep();` instead use implicit or explicitwait conditions

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: 1. At first, we are clicking on needed element. 2. At second, we have to waiting for our element full rendered on our page - for this we are writing `Thread.sleeps(milisec)`. 3. After that we are sure that our element is present on page and we can do with him any manipulations.